# What is the iOS to display the clock in iOS7 app development?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am developing an iOS app in iOS 7 that requires me to display a particular time.

Though this is not a programming question exactly, can anyone suggest me the component that allows me to display the time in a nice analog clock?

Answer (score 0):

Did you search [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) for example? This is the pleace where you can find lots of cocoa visual components like [clocks](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=clock).